# Simple form submit without page refresh issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have simple application whose functionality works fine, I'm just having trouble making it user friendly. Basically it is a form where the users enters his name (required) and his request (also required).

When the form is submitted, his entry is stored in a MySQL database and on the same page all other requests from all users are shown, including the users request. All this should be done without page refresh (which is basically my problem).

My HTML code structure is as follows:

```
<div id="main">
    <form action="" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
      Request: <textarea name="request"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="totalRequest">
  <!-- All requests fetched from database, including user's input -->
</div>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  //form validation code

  //if validation successful, execute code and send to MySQL
}
?>
```

To summarize, the user journey should be as follows:

User visits the page and sees the form, and other requests made by other people in the (#totalRequests) div. He then enters his own input (both fields required), and when validated, he should see his request displayed on top of the other requests.

I am not good with JavaScript or AJAX (at all). I know there are many tutorials online that offer similar projects, but all of them were either too complicated, or just not functioning the way I want them too.

I am not asking for a very big or advanced thing, I want the simplest solution possible. It doesn't need to be pretty or appealing to the eye as long as it gets the job done.

Sorry for taking so long, and thank you in advance.

Comment: So you are basically asking how to make an Ajax request? Read the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Try this: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: If your not good at it or it is to complicated you should hire someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to submit data to the webserver without refreshing the page unless you use Jquery or AJAX.